# Using Sentiwordnet 3.0

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, wordnet, sentiment-analysis, senti-wordnet

I plan on using Sentiwordnet 3.0 for Sentiment classification. Could someone clarify as to what the numbers associated with words in Sentiwordnet represent? For e.g. what does 5 in rank#5 mean? Also for POS what is the letter used to represent adverbs? Im assuming 'a' is adjectives. I could not find an explanation either on their site or on other sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer. Seems like the number notation comes form Wordnet. It represents the rank in which the given word is commonly used. So rank#5 refers to the context in which rank is used 5th most commonly. Similarly rank#1 refers to the meaning of rank most commonly used. The following are the POS notations:

n  -  NOUN 
v  -  VERB 
a   - ADJECTIVE 
s    - ADJECTIVE SATELLITE 
r    - ADVERB

Comment: The #5 is the word sense number.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you please provide the source?